# SQL IF value LIKE

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-like

I’m new to SQL, so apologies for what is probably a menial question.

I’m storing staff numbers in a format similar to `‘e01, e02 .. e98, e99’`

I have a procedure to input values into the employee table that I only want to be carried out if the provided value for the staff number field is the same format as shown above.

I have tried ..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_staff (IN e_id employee ids,
                ….,
                ….,etc)
BEGIN
IF e_id not like 'e__'
   THEN /* fail*/

ELSE /* insert record*/
END
```

I tested this  using the value ‘e9999’ and it didn't recognise the error, it instead just took the value 'e99'. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

-Edit-
Sorry - To clear things up. I'm using SQL Anywhere and I want the maximum possible employee id to be e99. My logic was that using like `e__` (two underscores) would make it impossible to input e100 or higher.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? And please post the full sql script code.

Comment: please explain clearer what you mean with 'error'. i think this is a bit unclear.

Comment: Sorry - To clear things up. I'm using SQL Anywhere and I want the maximum possible employee id to be e99. My logic was that using like 'e__' (two underscores) would make it impossible to input e100 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:***

Try it the other way round

```
IF e_id like 'e__'  
   THEN 
   /* insert record*/  
ELSE   
  /* fail*/
END
```

If you want the wildcards to be only numbers, try this one:

```
IF e_id like 'e[0-9][0-9]'  
   THEN 
   /* insert record*/  
ELSE   
  /* fail*/
END
```

For further information on SQL-Wildcards visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Comment: "I tested this using the value `e9999` and it didn't recognise the error", therefore `e9999` should be an error, so `e%` is _wrong_.

Comment: i think he wants to fail if e_id starts with an 'e'. No matter how long the following number is.

Comment: I am not the original poster; comment on the question please. And I agree, the question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using global symbols (e%):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE new_staff     (IN e_id employee ids,   
      ….,
                ….,etc)
BEGIN
IF e_id not like 'e%'
   THEN /* fail*/

ELSE /* insert record*/
END
```

Comment: How is this different from the Obl's wrong answer? Seems just as wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

Parse everything after 'e' and see if the value is <100.
or
Add a column that supports integers and one column for the letter prefix - assuming that the e prefix is code for something and that it could be something besides e.
 when returning the value just create a string with the prefix and add to it the string representation of your integer.

Comment: I'm looking back on this a year later. I took my own advise on it. Our companies job structure is M[yy]-[###] where M represents the fact that it's a job, yy last two digits of year and ### is the linear job number for that year. Been working great.